# Detecting a Reverted Transaction with Web3

Tags: contract-development, web3js, metamask

I am using Web3 to submit transactions and it seems as though whenever a transaction is successfully mined but reverted I don't get that error on my frontend. Is there anyway to detect when the transaction is reverted with Web3 so I can display an appropriate message on the front end?

The code I am using is below.

Thanks!

```
 web3.contractInstance().methods.create().send({gas: 90000, value: 10, from: address})
                        .on('transactionHash', hash => {
                            console.log('TX Hash', hash)
                        })
                        .then(receipt => {
                            console.log('Mined', receipt)
                        })
                        .catch( err => {
                            console.log('Error', err)
                        })
                        .finally(() => {
                            console.log('Extra Code After Everything')
                        })
```

I receive the receipt but no error on revert. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can get this in status field of receipt. If status is 1, it means the transaction was successful, if 0, it means transaction failed.

```
web3.contractInstance().methods.create().send({gas: 90000, value: 10, from: address})
                        .on('transactionHash', hash => {
                            console.log('TX Hash', hash)
                        })
                        .then(receipt => {
                            console.log('Mined', receipt)
                            if(receipt.status == '0x1' || receipt.status == 1){
                                console.log('Transaction Success')
                            }
                            else
                                console.log('Transaction Failed')
                        })
                        .catch( err => {
                            console.log('Error', err)
                        })
                        .finally(() => {
                            console.log('Extra Code After Everything')
                        })
```

This ability was introduced by [EIP-658](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-658.md)