# How to know when a transaction is finished? (web3.js)

Tags: web3js, contract-invocation, confirmations

I make a contract method call using `.send()` method:

```js
    contractInstance.methods.pay(itemId).send({from: defaultAccount, value: web3.utils.toWei(String(price*1.0000001)), gas: '1000000'},
                                              function(error, transactionHash) {
        if(error)
            alert("You tried to pay below the price or payment failure! " + err);
    })
```

How to be notified when the transaction fully happened (cannot be canceled by clicking Cancel in MetaMask anymore)? Is it called a confirmation?

If I just add `.on('confirmation')`:

```js
    contractInstance.methods.pay(itemId).send({from: defaultAccount, value: web3.utils.toWei(String(price*1.0000001)), gas: '1000000'},
                                              function(error, transactionHash) {
        if(error)
            alert("You tried to pay below the price or payment failure! " + err);
    })
        .on('confirmation', function(receipt){ showFilesWithMessage(); });
```

it does nothing (`showFilesWithMessage()` is not called).

web3.js 1.2.9.

---

Addition:

When I "follow the example on the official docs":

```js
    contractInstance.methods.pay(itemId).send({from: defaultAccount, value: web3.utils.toWei(String(price*1.0000001)), gas: '1000000'})
        .on('transactionHash', function(hash){
            console.log('transactionHash');
        })
        .on('receipt', function(receipt){
            console.log('receipt');
        })
        .on('confirmation', function(confirmationNumber, receipt) {
            console.log('confirmation', confirmationNumber);
            showFilesWithMessage();
        })
        .on('error', console.error); // If a out of gas error, the second parameter is the receipt.
```

the `confirmation` event is not issued either! Instead I get *only* `transactionHash` event.

How to get the confirmation event for `.send()`?

Comment: Is this the right answer to my question? https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/67234/36438

Comment: `If I just add...` - how exactly do you add it? Please share a complete piece of code, not fragments of it. Otherwise, it is impossible to tell you what exactly you are doing wrong.

Comment: @goodvibration Done.

Comment: Well you can't use both `.on` and a callback function passed as one of the parameter. If you wanna catch all 4 events (transaction hash, receipt, error and 24 confirmations), then get rid of the fallback and follow the example on the official docs.

Comment: @goodvibration But which of the events I need to catch to know when the transaction has become irreversible (not anymore cancelable by the user)?

Comment: It's never irreversible (and not by the user BTW, but by the entire participants of the network). Typically, it is estimated that 12 confirmations are sufficient for assuming permanency with a probability of 99.9999%. So you can catch 12 of those I suppose.

Comment: @goodvibration But how MetaMask determines when it hides the Cancel button for the transaction? I want to show the message to the user at the same time, if possible.

Comment: Well, what about catching the 12 confirmations, as I suggested above?

Comment: @goodvibration As you suggested, I followed the example on the official docs as you suggested, but this does not help: the confirmation event is _not_ caught!

Comment: @goodvibration Apparently, this is a MetaMask 1.2.9 bug, see what I wrote on it: https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/2104#issuecomment-654899409