# web3.js: call event handler after N confirmations

Tags: web3js, events, confirmations

web3.js seems to call the event handler of an event directly upon confirmation. I would like to know if it is possible to call an event handler only after e.g. 5 confirmations using web3.js. Is that currently possible?

Comment: Just ignore the first 5 inside your callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Below is TypeScript code I use to wait for N confirmations for the transaction.

Example usage:

```
// Call a ERC-20 method
const promiEvent = return token.methods.approve(contractAddr, numberOfTokens).send({ from: userAddress });

promiEvent.on("txHash", (hash) => {
   // We get transaction hash from MetaMask right after the user presses Confirm
   const receipt = await waitTransaction(web3, hash, {blocksToWait: 5, internal: 5000})
   // Do something with transaction of 5 confirmations
 });
```

````
/**
 * Wait transactions to be mined.
 *
 * Based on https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Kaisle/await-transaction-mined/master/index.js
 */

import Web3 from "web3";

const DEFAULT_INTERVAL = 1500;

const DEFAULT_BLOCKS_TO_WAIT = 1;

interface Options {

  // Poll delay in milliseconds
  interval: number;

  // How many blocks to wait
  blocksToWait: number;
}

/**
 * Wait for one or multiple transactions to confirm.
 * 
 * Usage:
 * ```
 * const promiEvent = return this.oldToken.methods.approve(this.tokenSwapSmartContractAddress, inputs.fullBalance).send({ from: this.walletState.selectedAddress });
 * promiEvent.on("txHash", (hash) => {
 *  // We get transaction hash from MetaMask right after the user presses Confirm
 *  const receipt = await waitTransaction(web3, hash, {blocksToWait: 5, internal: 5000})
 *  // Do something with transaction of 5 confirmations
 * });
 * 
 * ```
 *
 * @param web3
 * @param txnHash A transaction hash or list of those
 * @param options Wait timers
 * @return Transaction receipt
 */
export function waitTransaction(
  web3: Web3,
  txnHash: string | string[],
  options: Options = null
): Promise<any> {
  const interval =
    options && options.interval ? options.interval : DEFAULT_INTERVAL;
  const blocksToWait =
    options && options.blocksToWait
      ? options.blocksToWait
      : DEFAULT_BLOCKS_TO_WAIT;
  var transactionReceiptAsync = async function(txnHash, resolve, reject) {
    try {
      var receipt = web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(txnHash);
      if (!receipt) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          transactionReceiptAsync(txnHash, resolve, reject);
        }, interval);
      } else {
        if (blocksToWait > 0) {
          var resolvedReceipt = await receipt;
          if (!resolvedReceipt || !resolvedReceipt.blockNumber)
            setTimeout(function() {
              // this.logger.debug("Polling");
              transactionReceiptAsync(txnHash, resolve, reject);
            }, interval);
          else {
            try {
              var block = await web3.eth.getBlock(resolvedReceipt.blockNumber);
              var current = await web3.eth.getBlock("latest");
              if (current.number - block.number >= blocksToWait) {
                var txn = await web3.eth.getTransaction(txnHash);
                if (txn.blockNumber != null) resolve(resolvedReceipt);
                else
                  reject(
                    new Error(
                      "Transaction with hash: " +
                        txnHash +
                        " ended up in an uncle block."
                    )
                  );
              } else
                setTimeout(function() {
                  transactionReceiptAsync(txnHash, resolve, reject);
                }, interval);
            } catch (e) {
              setTimeout(function() {
                transactionReceiptAsync(txnHash, resolve, reject);
              }, interval);
            }
          }
        } else resolve(receipt);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      reject(e);
    }
  };

  // Resolve multiple transactions once
  if (Array.isArray(txnHash)) {
    var promises = [];
    txnHash.forEach(function(oneTxHash) {
      promises.push(waitTransaction(web3, oneTxHash, options));
    });
    return Promise.all(promises);
  } else {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      transactionReceiptAsync(txnHash, resolve, reject);
    });
  }
}

/**
 * Check if the transaction was success based on the receipt.
 *
 * https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/45967/620
 *
 * @param receipt Transaction receipt
 */
export function isSuccessfulTransaction(receipt: any): boolean {

  // TODO:
  // Hack fix for WalletModal reporting status=false even
  // though the transaction clearly went through.
  // Likely a web3.js bug.
  // Events are still set even if the status is set false.


  // blockHash: "0xc57dbdc96983d558cccadb591299e029c517e2ae548b4a683eb6968ede460411"
  // blockNumber: 10005547
  // contractAddress: null
  // cumulativeGasUsed: 2923750
  // events:
  // Approval: {address: "0xAf30D2a7E90d7DC361c8C4585e9BB7D2F6f15bc7", blockHash: "0xc57dbdc96983d558cccadb591299e029c517e2ae548b4a683eb6968ede460411", blockNumber: 10005547, logIndex: 18, removed: false, …}
  // from: "0x9b3979464c0d9c79fc34a4d4e9177891c4ef0ddb"
  // gasUsed: 24773
  // status: false
  // to: "0xaf30d2a7e90d7dc361c8c4585e9bb7d2f6f15bc7"
  // transactionHash: "0x60781cd7c97281acc97d163641c6c211c47740f07abc36d63ce32ac158e9f9d2"
  // transactionIndex: 19
  if(receipt.events) {
    if(receipt.events.Approval || receipt.events.Staked || receipt.events.Swapped) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  if (receipt.status == "0x1" || receipt.status == 1) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
````